# Controlling package dependencies in Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, package

I have a Java project (in Eclipse) consisting of several packages. I would like to control the dependencies between packages so that, for example, one package couldn't use some other package in the project. The reason for this is that I am going to make a self-contained jar from a subset of packages.

Do I have to separate my project into several to achieve this or is there some tool or Eclipse plugin that does it?

Comment: I am not quite sure if you can prevent one package from being imported by another (though I would like to find that out), but I can recommend [Stan4J](http://stan4j.com) for tracking the dependencies. It works as an Eclipse plugin or a stand-alone application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well since [Aspectj](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) is now an Eclipse Project, I guess an Aspectj solution qualifies as well. AspectJ is great for policy enforcements like that, because it lets you create compile-time warnings and errors based on pointcuts. And if you use the [AspectJ Developer Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/), you get aspects up and running in Eclipse.

Here's a sample Policy Enforcement Aspect:

```
public aspect PolicyEnforcement {

  pointcut project1Call() : call(* com.project1..*.*(..));
  pointcut inProject1() : within(com.project1..*);
  pointcut project2Call() : call(* com.project2..*.*(..));
  pointcut inProject2() : within(com.project2..*);

  declare error : project1Call() && inProject2()
    : "Project2 is not allowed to access Project1";
  declare error : project2Call() && inProject1()
    : "Project1 is not allowed to access Project2";
}
```

Note: It's perfectly OK to use AspectJ like that during the development phase only without causing any runtime dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted. Also I am glad you've pointed me into the direction of AspectJ - it looks like an amazing project and I am going to learn more about it.

Comment: @vitaut then you *must* read [AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/). It's the only reasonable reference out there.